# How do I know when a YouTube video has paused or finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, youtube, youtube-api

I'm pulling videos onto a website via the YouTube Data API and would like to register a callback for when a video has paused or finished. Does an event fire once either of these actions take place? Is there a method that detects whether a video has paused or finished?

Comment: READ the documentation. Pay attention to onPlayerStateChange in the example shttps://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Subscribe to events**

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}
```

More info on https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#SubscribingEvents